# Pick $2$ number randomly from $1$ to $n$ what is the probability of one number being smaller than $k$ and other one is greater than $k$?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

We need to pick $2$ number randomly from $1$ to $n$. what is the probability of one number being smaller than $k$ $(1<K<n)$ and the other one is greater than $k$?

#### My attempt

Here I assumed whatever $k$ is gonna be, it doesn't matter as one number will be always greater than the other number.

Given a set of numbers: $1 - n$.

Number of ways the first number can be picked is : $n$ (any number between $1 - n$)

Number of ways the second. number can be picked is : $n$ (any number between $1 - n$)

Total Combination is $n \times n = n^{2}$.

Now to pick the numbers in such a way that one is greater than the other,

Number of ways the first number can be picked is : $n$ (any number between $1 -n$)

Number of ways the second. number can be picked is : $n-1$ (any number other than the first number)

favorable combinations we get is $n(n-1)$

The probability that the two numbers picked between 1 to n, where one number is greater than the other, is : $\dfrac{n(n-1)}{n^{2}} = \dfrac{n-1}{n}$.

I am not sure whether am I right or wrong?

Comment: So, you are saying that if you pick  two numbers from $1$ to $1000$ inclusive , the proabability that one is less than $10$ and the other is greater than $10$ is $999/1000$?

Comment: You misread the question. You are computing the probability that you don't pick the same number twice (so that one number is larger than the other). The question is asking for the probability that one number is smaller than some fixed number $k$ and the other number is bigger than that fixed number $k$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng yea, but it doesn't make sense right. confused

Comment: @angryavian yea, I noticed that. My solution is invalid in this case

Comment: When you pick your two numbers, might they sometimes be the same (with replacement), or will they always be different (without replacement)

Comment: @Henry as it doesn't say explicitly.. we are considering both case

Comment: You cannot just vandalize your question. That is a sheer disrespect to all the answers and helps that other users provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $n-k$ numbers greater than $k$ and $k-1$ numbers smaller. Thus Your probability should be $2\times\frac{(n-k)\times(k-1)}{n^{2}}$

Comment: why have you included 2? is it because of the 2 numbers

Comment: @Transhumanist yes, because the big number can be the first one or the second one

Comment: You might need to adjust this slightly if the two numbers picked are without replacement

Comment: @Henry without replacement, just replace $n^{2}$ with $n(n-1)$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja ok understood.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are:

$$1,2,3,\dots,n$$

So we have a total of $n$ numbers.

Probability of selecting a number between $1$ and $k$, including $1$ and excluding $k$, is $\frac{k-1}{n}$

Probability of selecting a number between $k$ and $n$, excluding $k$ and including $n$, is $\frac{n-1}{n}$

Also, since we have two numbers, the can be permuted in $2!=2$ ways

Therefore, the probability of selecting two numbers, exactly on of them less than $k$ is given by:

$$P=\frac{2(k-1)(n-1)}{n^2}$$

Comment: I think you are allowed to pick $1$, and your $n-2$ may have an error

Comment: @Henry You are right, Check it now please dear. Thanks.

Comment: $n^{2}$ means your number is ordered i.e. $2,5$ and $5,2$ are different. However, in Your numerator, they are counted as one.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja in that case he just needs to multiply it by 2. right?

Comment: @Transhumanist correct

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja You are right, I will edit it.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja in his solution doesn't it be n-k rather than n-1, if its n-1 then we are including k as well. what do you think?

Comment: @Transhumanist oh yeah i missed that, should be $n-k$

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways to arrange $3$ numbers is $3!=6$.  In two of these arrangements, $k$ is in the middle.  So the probability is $1/3.$

Comment: I think $k$ is supposed to be given and you only pick two numbers